# Does Socks v5 encrypt the all traffic?

Tags: networking, vpn, encryption, socks5

I just found Socks concept and I'm trying to understand more about it and can understand the difference with other proxy and all kinds of vpn

- Does Socks v5 encrypt the all traffic?
- Can you look at this [client](https://shadowsocks.org) and explain its difference with
  other implementations?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Socks v5 encrypt the all traffic?

No.

However, some software present a SOCKS proxy *locally* (i.e. on `localhost`) and translate it to a custom protocol across the network, which *may* be encrypted. For example, that's how Tor works, as well as `ssh -D` dynamic tunnels.

> Can you look at this client and explain its difference with other implementations?

Shadowsocks is not a SOCKS 5 client. It uses [a custom protocol](https://shadowsocks.org/en/spec/Protocol.html) over the network, and only presents a SOCKS-compatible interface *locally* – exactly like my earlier Tor and SSH examples.

```
                Your computer                             Internet
┌─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ client --[SOCKS 5]--> ss-client ==[Shadowsocks]==> ss-server --[TCP]--> destination
└─────────────────────────────────────────┘

--- plaintext
=== encrypted
```